# Should the following queries not produce the same result? (MySQL)

Tags: mysql

Assuming the following **MySQL** table structure, why do the two following queries produce different results?

```
games(id) (464 records)
members(id) (1 record, id=351)
gameslists(id,memberid,gameid) -- (2 records, (1,351,1) and (2,351,2))
```

This produces null

```
SELECT games.* 
FROM games 
INNER JOIN gameslists ON gameslists.gameid = games.id 
WHERE gameslists.memberid <> 351 AND gameslists.id is NULL
```

This produces 462 records, which is what I expect.

```
SELECT games.* 
FROM games
LEFT JOIN gameslists ON gameslists.gameid = games.id AND gameslists.memberid <> 351
WHERE gameslists.id is NULL
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expression `(gameslists.id is NULL)` can never be true in the [`INNER JOIN`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)#Inner_join) query (assuming `id` is the primary key). That's why the first result set contains no rows.

On the other hand, whenever the `ON` clause of the [`LEFT JOIN`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)#Left_outer_join) does not match, the  `gameslists` fields will be `NULL` for that particular row. Therefore your second query will return all the `games` that do not appear in `gameslists`, unless `memberid` is `351`.

Comment: Not, an error, but also nulls: LEFT JOIN gameslists ON gameslists.gameid = games.id
WHERE gameslists.id is NULL AND gameslists.memberid <> 352

Comment: @Mel: What is the intended result? You want all games that do not appear in gameslists? And what about memberid?

Comment: The intended result is achieved in my second query (that returns 462 results; I want to select all games that do not exist in gameslists given a certain memberid); I would like to know if I can achieve the same thing by moving the "AND gameslists.memberid = ???" clause from the JOIN part to the WHERE part of the query. Why? They framework I'm using will not allow me to have two arguments in the JOIN clause (it will join gameslists.gameid = games.id, but I can't have the "AND gameslists.memberid" clause at the same time.

Comment: @Mel: What I can't understand is the `memberid` field. Because you're selecting all `games` that do not exist in `gameslist`, and `memberid` is a field in `gameslist`. Therefore by definition, all `games` that do not have an entry in `gameslist` will not have a `memberid` field.

Comment: The reason for memberid is this: Say a member has added two games. I want to eliminate those two games for him only, hence the condition needs to be double not (gameslists.gameid = games.id AND gamelists.memberid <> session.member.id)... if I don't have memberid as a filter, and all the games are added to lists, no one will be able to see anything any more!

Answer (score 2):

`INNER JOIN` returns non NULL matches, whereas `LEFT JOIN` can be NULL on one side. I think this is the clue.